# Is there a way to make Shehechiyanu when lighting the second night of Chanuka?

Tags: chanuka, riddle, shehecheyanu

How is it possible that someone lit the Menora on the first night of Chanuka, said Shehechiyanu, yet when he lights the Menora on the second night he would have to say Shehechiyanu again?

Comment: This looks like a riddle... Do you have an answer in mind? How do you know that this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe he is being motzei somebody else?
Or maybe it is a new, expensive menorah?
(I'll just ignore the possibility of international dateline/space travel issues for now)

Comment: I do not know about being Motzi someone else, however the Nitei gavriel brings that the Maharshal would wear a new Beged and say a Shehechiyanu on night 2 as the first night was for the Nitzachon in the war, and the rest of the nights was for the Neis of the Shemen. He mentions if you have a new expensive Menora you can also make a Shehechiyanu.

Comment: @GershonGold If you wear a new Beged on the fourth night you would also say shehechiyanu. And if you ate 7 new fruits on the first day you could say 7 shehechiyanus. Why is this interesting?

Answer (score 1):

A child who became Bar Mitzvah between lighting on the first night and lighting on the second ?

Comment: If he lit the first night he would not say Shehechiyanu on the second night.

Comment: R'GG, doubtless you're correct, but do you have a source?

Comment: @msh210 Why doubtless?